# Launch4j does not reflect the system outputs

Tags: launch4j

I am using Launch4j to create executable file of my application jar. I have put some system outputs (using System.out.println) which are very helpful for debugging (which I see when I run the jar file). But when I am using Launch4j to "test wrapper", I do not see any of these system outputs. Though my application runs properly, the system outputs will be very helpful.
I found a similar kind of unanswered question here http://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/discussion/332684/thread/f65d1979/#a845

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and found what I needed in this post:

[launch4j exe has nothing to say for itself, anyone got a suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068133/launch4j-exe-has-nothing-to-say-for-itself-anyone-got-a-suggestion)

In the Launch4j configuration GUI, set the "header type" to "console" in the "Header" tab.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I read this post before but for this I have to test on Windows. Currently I was trying to test on Linux by clicking on "test wrapper" blue button on Launch4j. But it looks like this is the only option I have. So I will go for it.  Thanks again